# Regex: Search for string containing 4 -

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to go through a log file line by line and find instances of strings like `5x76fd63-df62-4dae-a92b-10b8f38fb275` i.e having 4 dashes.

I need all the lines but want to use matched strings as key/ids.

Comment: Your question could be improved by showing what you have tried

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You don't even need a regex for that.

Comment: @gmds, what is the better solution? Indexing? That's a bit more complex, but yea, what's the better solution?

Comment: @FailSafe Purely for finding lines with 4 dashes? `line.count('-') == 4`. I'm not sure what OP means by "use matched strings as key/ids" though.

Comment: Ah, yes. I totally forgot about the count method. OMG, years sine Python101 lol. Excellent!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need all the lines but want to use matched strings as key/ids.

Since you want keys, a dictionary is appropriate.

```
import re
keyline = {}                                    # start with empty dictionary
for line in file:
    m = re.search("\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+", line)  # search ID with four dashes
    if m:
        keyline[m.group()] = line               # store the line with its ID

print(keyline)
```